# Hiding text in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I use timeout (timeout /t2) with echo off I am getting output as below:

```
@echo off
timeout /t 2
@echo on
```

Output

```
-->Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ..
```

I want to hide the above text in cmd.

Comment: P.S you don't need to do `@echo on`, it'll be automatically set to `ON` after the batch script ends.

Comment: Added windows as a tag as this is specific to Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Redirect the output with `>NUL`, as `@echo off` only supresses the output of the command line itself, not of the output of the command.

```
@echo off 
timeout /t 2 > nul
```

Comment: That still leaves error messages going to the command line which is probably what you want.

Comment: What type of errors do you expect from `timeout`? _Sorry the time stands still_ or _The end of time has reached_

Comment: Since the location of the timeout command hasn't been specified, it is possible that an unexpected command could be run. In that case the parameters may be wrong. When scripting things, you always need to "expect the unexpected" as Monty Python would say.

Comment: @JulianKnight It hasn't been specified because it's in `PATH`, no one is going to specify the exact path to every command they use.

Comment: @BaliC, I know that. I think people are making too much of the comment. I was pointing out that the answer only intercepts the stdout and not the stderr and that was, indeed, *probably* what was wanted but since we don't have the context in which the question was asked, trapping stderr *could* be important, we simply don't know. Perhaps this is a *part* of a security script? In that case, not using the path may be important too - even though unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
timeout 5 >nul
@echo on
```

Comment: I added the code snippet to a code block for better readability.  And added a missing line to make it actually it work.